# Unable to import json simple's .jar file into JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, json-simple

I have copied the `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. In `index.jsp`, I am writing: 
`<%@ page import="org.json.simple.parse.JSONParser" %>`.

But this gives me the error:

```
An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.json.simple.parse.JSONParser resolves to a package
```

I have seen other questions with this error but they all point to pasting the jar file into the right folder. I've already done that. What am I missing? Is there something I need to write in the Catalina host config by any chance? The virtual host for this in `server.xml` is:

```
<Host name="test-jsp.dev" appBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/test-jsp.dev"></Host>
```

Maybe an XML attribute I'm not setting?

I have already restarted the server. Also double checked that the group/owner of the jar file is `root`, because that's the way it is in the `webapps/ROOT` folder.

Comment: did you retsart your server?

Comment: Yes, `sudo service tomcat7 restart`. Problem did not resolve.

Comment: are u sure that json-simple-X.X.jar available in your application Lib folder

Comment: Not an answer, but you should not use scriptlets in JSPs anyway. JSPs are view components, using the EL, the JSTL and other custom tags to generate HTML from a model prepared by a controller. The controller, written in Java, as a servlet (for example), should be where you parse your JSON.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I'll keep that in mind for real world projects. Right now rushing for something ;)

Comment: @NaveenRamawat, do you mean in `WEB-INF/lib`? Yes. Is there any other folder?

Comment: are you sure the file is not corrupted in any way?

Comment: You need to add ";" at the end of your import. Can you try <%@ page import="org.json.simple.parse.JSONParser;" %>

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I had downloaded the file a couple times and tried just in case, same thing happened.

Comment: @Hirak yes I saw that in another question and tried it out but didn't work :(

Comment: Could this be a file permission issue? I changed the group of the jar to tomcat7 and made sure all have read and execute permissions... no luck yet.

Comment: Do you find this class `JSONParser` located inside your jar . i mean the required package

Comment: Yes, I used [Jar Explorer](https://code.google.com/p/jar-explorer/) to verify that the class [actually exists](http://imgur.com/51aw0mM).